# Outlook Addin: "Tell me more" text in Ribbon item hover

Tags: outlook-addin, ribbon-control

When I move mouse over a Ribbon item in my custom Outlook Addin, there is a tooltip which mentions the name of the Addin and a link "Tell me more". Upon pressing this, it directs me to MS Lynk web page. How can I customize this in order to be directed to an alternative link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Fluent UI doesn't provide anything for that. You can read more about the Fluent UI (aka Ribbon UI) in the following series of articles in MSDN:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338199(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa722523(v=office.12).aspx)

Comment: I can open all hyperlinks from the post in my web browser.